# Impossible to find module - OpenCV for UPW platform

Tags: c++, opencv, uwp, windows-runtime

I'm trying to develop an UWP application which has to use the OpenCV library.

The code simply access the camera and returns:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
int TEST::OpenCam()
{
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    if(!cap.IsOpened())
    {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I've tried to create a WinRT component in c++ which link to OpenCV native libraries, the project compile succesfully but at runtime the whole application crash with the following error:

**FileNotFoundException Impossible to find the specified module
Exception from HRESULT 0x8007007E**

I got this exception if I `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>` and only if working with UWP, the same code works perfectly on a windows console application.

I've tried to compile OpenCv for UWP using following links but I got some problems:

1. [OpenCV: building UWP binaries](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lucian/2015/11/27/opencv-building-uwp-binaries/)
2. [Build OpenCV for UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47773560/build-opencv-for-uwp?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

The visual studio solution won't fully build because ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj isn't found in the build directory even if it succesfully build.

Cmake for windows give me an error saying that can't find a Visual Studio 15 2017 instance.

I don't know if I've missed something in previous steps but actually I'm not figuring out how to use this library in UWP.
Is there a way to use OpenCV inside an UWP app or I must recompile the whole library against that platform?

Comment: Have you check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/process-software-bitmaps-with-opencv)?